# SQL Server Magement Studio - View sysobjects table in Explorer

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

This seems simple enough, but can't see to find any information on it.  All I want to is view the table definition for sysobjects in Object Explorer along with all of the other system tables.  I know I can jus select * from sysobjects, but I want to see all of the other system table definitions as well in object explorer.  When I open up system tables under my database, all I see is dbo.sysdiagrams.  Help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may be able to get what you need from the `sys.objects` **[VIEW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx)**.

Under your DB go to `Views-->System Views` to see your options.

Comment: +1. From SQL 2005 the system tables were hidden: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3508881/SQL-Server-2005-System-Tables-and-Views.htm

Comment: Thanks.  I knew about the system views, however, I want to see the all of the actual system tables that the views point to.

Comment: @AdaTheDev - I tried this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190644.aspx, still no luck.

Comment: @Thenoob - the point is, you can't.  Read the article Ada posted.  Even full admins can't directly interact with them in SQL Server 2005+

Comment: @JNK - Got it.  So the next best thing is the views which everyone has pointed to.  Will use that instead.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Thenoob - also it is considered polite on Stack Overflow to accept an answer (this gives both you and the answerer reputation).  FWIW, @Marc's is prettier than mine :)

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Scroll down quite a bit, and you should find the `sys.sysobjects` system catalog view and be able to select from it.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the help.  I may just have to settle with using the views to interface with those tables.  I was really hoping to get at the actual tables themselves jus in case, but looks like the views kind of give me the same thing.

Comment: @thenoob - the views are actually better.  You have a lot more options with the views, and there's less risk of you messing up some metadata accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

They should appear under the Database node, though they might be [hidden](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190644.aspx).

Comment: I just went to that option, and it is unchecked meaning they should show up.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @thenoob - have you refreshed the tree view?